AWS api gateway + cognito (How to pass user attributes to the backend service)
I got aws api gateway with cognito authorizer. I want to get information on the backend (spring application) about who was logged in. The user attributes should be sended to the backend via http headers.
The api-gateway should return my request with additional information about user. Username/Email

Are you using HTTP integration or Lambda integration? Are you using proxy integration?

I'm currently using Lambda integration for testing. But in the future i will use HTTP integration with application on Elastic Beanstalk
